# Apache: How to tell which LDAP server my user was authenticated with

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, ldap

I am authenticating my users with the following configuration (simplified)

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap server1>
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://server1/whatever?uid?one?
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap server2>
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://server2/whatever?uid?one?
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<Location />
  AuthName "Realm"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider server1 server2
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
  require valid-user
</Location>
```

Is there any way I can know if which LDAP server my user was authenticated from? When the authentication is sucessful I'd like to set an HTTP header (something like "SourceLDAPServer: server2") to be able to tell which server the user was valid in. Is that possible with Apache 2.2.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way to do this is to select more attributes from the LDAP servers like so:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap server1>
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://server1/whatever?uid,type1?one?
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap server2>
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://server2/whatever?uid,type2?one?
</AuthnProviderAlias>
```

When the authentication succeeds you find either `AUTHENTICATE_type1` or `AUTHENTICATE_type2` as environment variables depending on which LDAP server did the authentication.

With mod_headers, it then becomes possible to setup the header value this way

```
Header set UserType type1 env=AUTHENTICATE_type1
Header set UserType type2 env=AUTHENTICATE_type2
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible with Apache [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html). I don't know about the environment variables mod_ldap would use, though. If you have PHP installed, just create a PHP file containing line

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And surf to that file. See the environment variables printed in that page and try to find out if there are any ldap variables around.