# Apache reverse proxy with Kerberos authenticate and LDAP authorization

Tags: apache-2.4, ldap, kerberos, single-sign-on

Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
Apache is launched as a container in the Openshift cluster.

I am using Apache as a forward and reverse proxy for Kibana.

Mandatory requirement is use Kerberos and need a role model to differentiate access.
I created in elasticsearch admin and viewer users.
Depending on the LDAP group, the Apache must transmit either a header with the administrator's login and password, or a viewer.
But there is no way I can get it.

- My config:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-access>
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.example.com:389/dc=example,dc=com?cn?sub?(objectClass=user)"
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=ServiceAccount,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "password"
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthzProviderAlias ldap-group ldap-group-viewer CN=viewer,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com>
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.example.com:389/dc=example,dc=com?cn?sub?(objectClass=user)"
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=ServiceAccount,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "password""
</AuthzProviderAlias>

<AuthzProviderAlias ldap-group ldap-group-admin CN=admin,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com>
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.example.com:389/dc=example,dc=com?cn?sub?(objectClass=user)"
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=ServiceAccount,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "password""
</AuthzProviderAlias>


<LocationMatch "/kibana">
    AuthType GSSAPI
    AuthName "Kerberos Auth"

    GssapiSSLonly Off
    GssapiBasicAuth On
    GssapiAllowedMech krb5

    GssapiSessionKey file:/tmp/session.key
    GssapiCredStore keytab:/etc/httpd/krb5.keytab
    GssapiCredStore ccache:FILE:/var/run/httpd/krb5ccache
    GssapiDelegCcacheDir /var/run/httpd/clientcaches
    GssapiImpersonate On
    GssapiLocalName On

    GssapiUseSessions On
    Session On
    SessionExpiryUpdateInterval 300
    SessionInclude /
    SessionCookieName gssapi_session path=/;httponly;secure;
    
    BrowserMatch Windows gssapi-no-negotiate
    LogLevel debug

    AuthBasicProvider ldap-access
    <RequireAll>
      Require ldap-group-viewer
      Require ldap-group-admin
    </RequireAll>

    ProxyPass http://kibana:5601/kibana
    ProxyPassReverse http://kibana:5601/kibana

    RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic dmlld2VyOnZpZXdlcg=="
    
</LocationMatch>
```

In this configuration, all users in groups log in with the same login, but I need to share the rights.

- For viewers - RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic dmlld2VyOnZpZXdlcg=="
- For administrators - RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="

I tried to add an attribute to LDAP url and use a variable AUTHORIZATION_Viewer like here [Apache: How to tell which LDAP server my user was authenticated with](https://serverfault.com/questions/166203/apache-how-to-tell-which-ldap-server-my-user-was-authenticated-with):

```
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.example.com:389/dc=example,dc=com?cn,Viewer?sub?(objectClass=user)"
```

And then:

```
RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic dmlld2VyOnZpZXdlcg==" env=AUTHENTICATE_Viewer
```

But in Apache logs such a variable does not appear at all.

Also tried the option with the  block, but unsuccessfully.

Is there any way to create a semblance of a role model in the Apache?